# Compute component scores from principal$loadings directly in R

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I am using a polychoric correlation matrix to run PCA, so I cannot obtain the scores directly from the function. I am currently manually plugging in the numbers from the `principal$loadings` matrix to calculate the factor scores, like this:

```
            RC1    RC2   
    Q1  0.323  0.808
    Q2 -0.306  0.867
    Q3 ......
    .......

RC1 <- Q1*0.323-Q2*0.306+...
RC2 <- Q1*0.808+Q2*0.867+...
```

I think that there should be a better way to perform this calculation. Is there any way that will allow me to compute this easier?

Comment: Providing a _minimal working example (MWE)_ would be helpful.

Comment: Can't you just do matrix multiplication? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Aaron, Arrgh I forgot about matrix multiplication!!! Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood what you're doing, I think that the easier way of computing component scores is either one of the following **approaches**. The first and, likely, the easiest, one is to use item response theory (IRT)-based R package `ltm` (see [this JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v17/i05/paper) for details and examples). The second approach is more traditional and uses popular `psych` package, along with `hetcor` package for computing polychoric correlations. *Minimal reproducible examples (MRE)* for both approaches can be found below.

Additionally, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32236/31372) and [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32136/31372), but keep in mind that `fa.poly()` function is deprecated, which IMHO seems to imply that `hetcor()` is now a preferred solution.

**Approach 1:**

```
library(ltm)
library(psych) # for 'bock' data set: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/psych/docs/bock

data(bock)

lsat.fit <- rasch(lsat6)
summary(lsat.fit)
ltm::factor.scores(lsat.fit)
```

**Results:**

```
Call:
rasch(data = lsat6)

Model Summary:
   log.Lik      AIC      BIC
 -2466.938 4945.875 4975.322

Coefficients:
            value std.err   z.vals
Dffclt.Q1 -3.6153  0.3266 -11.0680
Dffclt.Q2 -1.3224  0.1422  -9.3009
Dffclt.Q3 -0.3176  0.0977  -3.2518
Dffclt.Q4 -1.7301  0.1691 -10.2290
Dffclt.Q5 -2.7802  0.2510 -11.0743
Dscrmn     0.7551  0.0694  10.8757

Integration:
method: Gauss-Hermite
quadrature points: 21 

Optimization:
Convergence: 0 
max(|grad|): 2.9e-05 
quasi-Newton: BFGS 



Call:
rasch(data = lsat6)

Scoring Method: Empirical Bayes

Factor-Scores for observed response patterns:
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Obs     Exp     z1 se.z1
1   0  0  0  0  0   3   2.364 -1.910 0.790
2   0  0  0  0  1   6   5.468 -1.439 0.793
3   0  0  0  1  0   2   2.474 -1.439 0.793
4   0  0  0  1  1  11   8.249 -0.959 0.801
5   0  0  1  0  0   1   0.852 -1.439 0.793
6   0  0  1  0  1   1   2.839 -0.959 0.801
7   0  0  1  1  0   3   1.285 -0.959 0.801
8   0  0  1  1  1   4   6.222 -0.466 0.816
9   0  1  0  0  0   1   1.819 -1.439 0.793
10  0  1  0  0  1   8   6.063 -0.959 0.801
11  0  1  0  1  1  16  13.288 -0.466 0.816
12  0  1  1  0  1   3   4.574 -0.466 0.816
13  0  1  1  1  0   2   2.070 -0.466 0.816
14  0  1  1  1  1  15  14.749  0.049 0.836
15  1  0  0  0  0  10  10.273 -1.439 0.793
16  1  0  0  0  1  29  34.249 -0.959 0.801
17  1  0  0  1  0  14  15.498 -0.959 0.801
18  1  0  0  1  1  81  75.060 -0.466 0.816
19  1  0  1  0  0   3   5.334 -0.959 0.801
20  1  0  1  0  1  28  25.834 -0.466 0.816
21  1  0  1  1  0  15  11.690 -0.466 0.816
22  1  0  1  1  1  80  83.310  0.049 0.836
23  1  1  0  0  0  16  11.391 -0.959 0.801
24  1  1  0  0  1  56  55.171 -0.466 0.816
25  1  1  0  1  0  21  24.965 -0.466 0.816
26  1  1  0  1  1 173 177.918  0.049 0.836
27  1  1  1  0  0  11   8.592 -0.466 0.816
28  1  1  1  0  1  61  61.235  0.049 0.836
29  1  1  1  1  0  28  27.709  0.049 0.836
30  1  1  1  1  1 298 295.767  0.593 0.862
```

**Approach 2:**

```
library(polycor)
library(psych)

data(bock)

# calculate polychoric correlations
#lsat.corr <- polychoric(lsat6, smooth=TRUE, global=TRUE, polycor=F, ML = FALSE, std.err=FALSE, progress=TRUE)
lsat.corr <- hetcor(lsat6, ML=TRUE)

# perform PCA
lsat.pca <- principal(r = lsat.corr$correlations, nfactors = 3, rotate = "Promax")
summary(lsat.pca)

# compute factor scores from the 'lsat6' data set with the 'lsat.pca' PCA solution
lsat.pca$scores <- factor.scores(lsat6, lsat.pca)
print("")
print("Sample of calculated factor scores:")
print("")
print(head(lsat.pca$scores$scores))

# plot results
biplot.psych(lsat.pca)
```

**Results:**

```
Factor analysis with Call: principal(r = lsat.corr$correlations, nfactors = 3, rotate = "Promax")

Test of the hypothesis that 3 factors are sufficient.
The degrees of freedom for the model is -2  and the objective function was  1.2 

 With component correlations of 
     PC1  PC3  PC2
PC1 1.00 0.09 0.00
PC3 0.09 1.00 0.15
PC2 0.00 0.15 1.00

Sample of calculated factor scores:

           PC1        PC3       PC2
[1,] -2.656750 -2.6932246 -1.860959
[2,] -2.656750 -2.6932246 -1.860959
[3,] -2.656750 -2.6932246 -1.860959
[4,] -3.554983 -0.7170872 -1.031587
[5,] -3.554983 -0.7170872 -1.031587
[6,] -3.554983 -0.7170872 -1.031587
```

[image]

**NOTE:** In the second approach, I intentionally specified 3 factors to simplify the illustrative plot. However, I have also tried 5 factors and as of now still couldn't figure out why the results between the approaches are so different. Clarifications and/or explanations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: fa.poly is deprecated!? I have just learned it... Thank you for the details example!

Comment: I want to know why the results are so different too...

Comment: @ceoec: You're welcome! Thank you for upvoting/accepting my answer - I hope that it is helpful. In regard to `fa.poly()` being deprecated, that's the info I've found in the documentation, but it's just one reference, so I'm not 100% sure about that. In regard to results, I hope that other people will chime in and clarify that.